# Display function signature in completion popup menu instead of status line with SLIME/SLY in Emacs

Tags: company-mode, slime, common-lisp, sly

What the title says. I'd like the function signature for functions in Common Lisp to display next to the function name in the company-mode autocomplete popup menu instead of at the bottom of the editor, because then I'd have to move my eyes a lot less. I'm using SLY in Doom Emacs. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe submit an enhancement request to the relevant maintainer? If everything involved is part of vanilla Emacs, then `M-x report-emacs-bug` for an enhancement request.

Comment: I would have assumed its already an option, but if it isnt I'm gonna sit down and see if I can implement it myself sometime and send a patch!